# Como pegar o valor de uma variável de classe Java e printar num arquivo JSP

Tags: java

Estou tentando transferir o valor de um contador de consultas no banco de dados para uma variável de classe, para chama-la num arquivo JSP, o mesmo vai exibi-la numa pagina HTML. O problema é que quando chamo a variavel no JSP ele printa o valor de inicialização da variável, nesse caso 13. ME AJUDEM POR FAVOR!!!!!!

```
package novomongoteste;

import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.QueryBuilder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import static novomongoteste.ContatoTeste.b;

public class ContatoTeste {

    private IContatoDao<Contato> dao = new ContatoDao();
    public static int a = 13 // DECLARAÇÃO DA VARIAVEL DE CLASSE

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContatoTeste t = new ContatoTeste();

        t.findByName();


    }

    private void findByName() {
        DBObject query = QueryBuilder
                .start("uf")
                .regex(Pattern.compile("PB"))
                .get();

        List<Contato> contatos = dao.findContatos(query);

        int contador = 0;

        for (Contato contato : contatos) {

            contador += 1;
            System.out.println(contato.toString());                
        }
        System.out.println(contador);
        a = contador;  // ALOCAÇÃO DO VALOR DO CONTADOR PARA A VARIAVEL D CLASSE
    }
 }
```

********************************* CÓDIGO JSP **************************

```
    <%
        out.println(ContatoTeste.a);
    %>
```

Comment: Tira o código comentado da pergunta, pode ajudar na legibilidade e ai vamos poder te ajudar com mais rápidez, e posta seu código do JSP.

Comment: Cara, como você faz pra subir essa aplicação ?

Comment: To usando o NetBeans, utilizei uma função dele mesmo pra criar um aplicação WEB, o problema é que a variavel de classe que está sendo referenciada no JSP só é reconhecida com o valor global e não com o valor do contadador. Quando eu rodo o arquivo HTML no NetBeans ele abre uma pagina no navegador com um botão, pra printar o numero.

Comment: Você tem certeza que o método findByName tá sendo chamado?